# service refers to undefined volume

Tags: django, docker, celery

I want to share temp files between Django project and celery worker (it works with TemporaryUploadedFiles, so I want to have access to these files from celery worker to manage them). I've read about shared volumes, so I tried to imlement it in my docker-compose file and run it, but the command gave me this error:

```
$ docker compose up --build
service "web" refers to undefined volume shared_web_volume/: invalid compose project
```

And sometimes "web" replace with "celery", so both celery and django have no access to this volume.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
volumes:
  shared_web_volume:
  postgres_data:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  web:
    build:
      context: ./MoreEnergy
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: sh ./entrypoint.sh
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - "shared_web_volume/:/MoreEnergy/"
    ports:
      - 1337:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db
  celery:
    build:
      context: ./MoreEnergy
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: sh ./entrypoint.sh
    command: celery  -A MoreEnergy worker --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - "shared_web_volume/:/MoreEnergy/"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis:5-alpine
```

What am I doing wrong?

Upd: temp dir is my project folder (I've set it with `FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR` variable in settings file), so I don't need to make one more volume only for shared temp files (If I have to, tell me).

Answer (score 0):

your shared volume name is `shared_web_volume` and it's different from the one that you use in the volumes section which is `shared_web_volume/`

so my suggestion is to erase the forward slash to be like this

```
    volumes:
      - "shared_web_volume:/MoreEnergy/"
```

Don't forget to do the same thing in celery container

Answer (score 0):

You need a "dot slash" before the directory name.
So:

```
volumes:
  - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```